# Best/better way to handle (filter) BIG csv files?

Tags: node.js, csv, bigdata

I have many gb's worth of data each in a ~3-4gb uncompressed csv file.  I created a streaming function that scans each csv file for a value in a certain column and if it's true saves it to a single output file (shared by each input function).

What I saw though is that setting it to stream through 26 files (52 weeks in a year / 2 for a season) all at once takes about 8-9000 seconds (about 346 seconds a file).  While when I run a single file I get < 200 seconds.  Where am I creating 70% overhead?

My code is hopefully irrelevant, but for verbosity: I'm using a library named "byline" to stream the files.  Pretty sure my filtering is suboptimal (especially supporting multiple filters later on), but I'm currently only running 1 filter so that should be neutral to performance.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var byline = require('byline');

function readSkuData(afilename,col,value) {

    var stream = fs.createReadStream(afilename);

    stream = byline.createStream(stream);
    filters.push([col,value]);


    stream.on('data',function(line) {
        loaded = loaded + line.length;
        lineinfo = line.toString().split(",");

        if (!(lineFiltered(lineinfo,filters))) {
            filteredsize = filteredsize + 1;
            fs.appendFile('filteredData.csv',"\n" + line, function (err) { if (err) throw err;});
        }

    });

    stream.on('end',finishProcess);
}

function lineFiltered(line,filters) {
    for (i=0;i < filters.length;i++) {
        if (line[filters[i][0]] != filters[i][1]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would take a look at [papaparse](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse) or if you specifically want it for node.js then [babyparse](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/BabyParse)

Comment: I/O are not unlimited, reading 26 3GB files at once is more stressful for your disk than just one big file at a time. There is nothing wrong in processing files so big one by one.

Comment: Yeah I have babyparse in some of the later code.  I think I'll try to call the file reading sequentially rather than asynchronous.  Side question though: Lets say I implement on SSD (which is the plan later) will the asynchronous I/O still create lots of overhead?